# Request a web-page with a button press pre-selected?

Tags: php, button, web-scraping

Consider e.g. the webpage

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/NVDA/financials?p=NVDA

Right above the table on that website there are two buttons "Annual" and "Quarterly", which fill the table with corresponding values. By default the webpage loads with the "Annual" button pre-selected, so if I use `fopen` or `file_get_contents` in php to request that webpage the table arrives with that data.

Is there a way to request that page through php with the button "Quarterly" activated instead of "Annual"?

Answer (score 0):

While this does not answer the technical question, it provides a workaround:

https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/financials?query=income-statement&data=quarterly

the nasdaq website provides the same information with simple variable query in the link, so that it is not necessary to click any buttons on the page to switch information. Include `&data=quarterly` in the link for quarterly data, do not include it for annual data.